apg_plan_mgmt not in shared_preload_libraries
when trying to apply my plan i get this error,
 Error: pq: apg_plan_mgmt not in shared_preload_libraries

however, when i add it at as a param to my cluster like so
  parameter {
    name         = "shared_preload_libraries"
    value        = "apg_plan_mgmt,pg_stat_statements"
    apply_method = "pending-reboot"
  }

i get the error
Terraform v1.6.2
on linux_amd64
Initializing plugins and modules...
aws_rds_cluster_parameter_group.qpm_cluster_parameter_group: Creating...
╷
│ Error: InvalidParameterValue: Invalid parameter value: apg_plan_mgmt for: shared_preload_libraries allowed values are: auto_explain,orafce,pgaudit,pg_similarity,pg_stat_statements,pg_hint_plan,pg_prewarm,plprofiler,pglogical,pg_cron
│   status code: 400, request id: 3063e79b-0344-4d2b-8433-61d2cddc2fd4

How can I add apg_plan_mgmt library to the preloaded libs? I'd like to use it through terraform, but not sure if there is a sequence I need to follow in order to load it
I see from here
Terraform & RDS Postgres: why isn't pg_repack allowed in shared_preload_libraries? that I just need to create the extension, however when trying that, i got the original error

I am yet to try this with terraform but i believe the apg_plan_mgmt module should be loaded after enabling plan management in cluster parameter group and restarting the cluster.
Please let me know how you are able to address this.

The answer is speculative and lacks concrete steps or references. Please provide a detailed solution or clarify that this is a hypothesis.
